# How to use JQuery add number_field_tag's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry i'm new to using Javascript in Rails.

I have 4 number_field_tags.
Whenever a user enters a number, it will sum the numbers of all 4 number_field_tag. I would like to know how can i do that.

I've tried following this http://jsperf.com/jq-sum-elements-vs-raw-js but I don't know how to call the function out.

```
<td class="method2">
                <p>Input the number of each base the primer should have</p>
                <label>Number of A :</label>
                <%= number_field_tag(:no_A,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                <label>Number of T :</label>
                <%= number_field_tag(:no_T,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                <label>Number of G :</label>
                <%= number_field_tag(:no_G,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                <label>Number of C :</label>
                <%= number_field_tag(:no_C,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                Total bases:<span></span>
</td>
```

How can i show the current Total bases ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? If not, can you post some of the code you have so far? The more information, the more helpful the community can be.

Comment: nope i don't have the solution yet

Comment: Do you have any code snippets you can post that show what you're working with right now and what you are trying to get to?

Comment: Hi marcacyr, i've include the edited version .

Comment: I added a second answer to get you started on jQuery Validate. Sorry it took so long - the past week was crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I'm understanding your question correctly you have 4 things which have bases and you would like to dynamically show the user a total of bases as they enter the information in the number_field_tags. To achieve this, I took the code snippet above and assigned the class of "bases" to each of the number_field_tags and an id of "total-bases" to the span where you want to display the total.

```
<td class="method2">
  <p>Input the number of each base the primer should have</p>
  <label>Number of A :</label>
  <%= number_field_tag(:no_A,nil, in:0...36, class: 'bases') %><br />
  <label>Number of T :</label>
  <%= number_field_tag(:no_T,nil, in:0...36, class: 'bases') %><br />
  <label>Number of G :</label>
  <%= number_field_tag(:no_G,nil, in:0...36, class: 'bases') %><br />
  <label>Number of C :</label>
  <%= number_field_tag(:no_C,nil, in:0...36, class: 'bases') %><br />
  Total bases:<span id="total-bases"></span>
</td>
```

I then wrote the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("keyup change", ".bases", function() {
  totalSides();
});

function totalSides() {
  var tmp = 0;
  var total = 0;
  $(".bases").each(function() {
    tmp = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (isNaN(tmp)) {
      tmp = 0;
    };
    total = total + tmp;
  });
  $("#total-bases").html(total);
};
```

What this does is on any keyup or change inside the number_field_tag box, the function totalSides will run. The totalSides function sets a temporary variable (tmp) to 0 as well as setting the variable total to 0. It then iterates over each number_field_tag using the class "bases". It parses the contents to integers. If the input is not a number (isNaN), it dumps it by setting tmp to 0, otherwise it sets the variable total to the sum of the values inside all of the number_field_tags in your td.

It then sets the html in the span to this total.

I think this is what you were looking for and hopefully this helps. Let me know if you have further questions and I will do my best to help.

Just re-thought your validation question and realized, you could just use the built in number_field_tag options. You can use:

```
min: 6
max: 36
```

or even easier, us :in => 6...36

```
in: 6...37
```

as options on each number_field_tag. That's much simpler than my first idea... which would be using the jQuery Validation plugin library... though, the Validation library is a good thing to be familiar with when you want to do validations on things that aren't so easily added as options to the rails form helpers.

Your original code makes use of in: 0...36 - should be as easy as changing 0 to 6 and 36 to 37 to give you the range allowed as 6-36. If it's not, let me know and I will re-include some jQuery Validation code and set you on that path.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Here is some sample code for a method for jQuery validate:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("no-zero", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || !/^0$/.test(value);
}, "Cannot be zero.");
```

Basically, just replace the Regex with the right regex to validate a value between 6 and 36, and then write the error message you want thrown if the user violates it.

Comment: Thanks it is exactly what i'm trying to do. However is there a way to add validation to that ? I want to add validation tototal bases. In other words,total bases can only be 36 bases max and 6 as minimum.

Comment: There is a way to validate using the jQuery Validate plugin library. I updated the answer to give a little info for that to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Re-thought your question and updated the answer again to be a much simpler approach.

Comment: Note: the min and max in the form helper control the arrows and what a user can enter with those... for full-blown jQuery validation use the jQuery Validation plugin library: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

I can post sample code for using that library if you need.

Comment: erm each number field should have min 0 bcoz they can either have a A or none at all. THat's is why i use 0. Howvever the total maximum is only 36 and minimum 6. So i think i need the Jquery Validation

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. jQuery Validation is the way to go then. That way the user can leave it blank, but if they do enter a value you can check that it is between 6 and 36. I'll post something later to point you in the right direction on that.

Comment: Thanks marcacyr but if i may ask where should i paste that jQuery code? is it still in my html page ?

Comment: Hi BC2, I've been slammed for a few days, but will post an additional answer to cover the validation for you as soon as I have a spare few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

for using the jQuery Validate plugin library, there are a few things.

Download the jquery validate .min.js file and put it into your asset pipeline by putting it within the assets/javascripts directory.

Then in your application.js file put

```
//require jquery.validate.min
```

Then, inside of the jquery.validate.min.js file, you can put a method similar to this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("no-zero", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/^0$/.test(value);
}, "Cannot be zero.");
```

This is more or less how the syntax will always be - notice I used some generic names and such to show you where to put things.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("methodName", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /regex/.test(value);
}, "Error message here");
```

Write Regex to test for what you want to validate. To check your regex, a good site is www.rubular.com

To apply the validation in the view, you assign a class to the what you want to validate in your form. For example, right now you have

```
class: 'bases'
```

You would add to that and have something like

```
class: 'bases validation-method-name'
```

A good thing about this approach is you can reuse the validation throughout your app.

Almost forgot this:

You need to add a js file (or include something like the following in an existing js file) that you include on the page. You would have something like this:

```
$(".method2").validate();
```

This calls what you need to from jquery validate library to run the validation on the number_field_tags.

Comment: Note: this is for front-end validation. You should still investigate a way to add model validations as well to ensure better coverage.